# Domain of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given this function:
>
> $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{y-1-x}+\ln{(x-y^2+4y-3)}$$
>
> Characterize the domain.

---

I isolated $y$ for the expressions under the square root and inside the natural logarithm. I got the following:

[image]

The domain is the space where the two graphs overlap, right? Around $y=2$. How do I describe this accurately? My take is that the domain is limited but continuous.

Comment: you have two conditions $$y-1-x\geq 0$$ and $$x-y^2+4y-3>0$$

Comment: So I should solve the inequalities for $y$ to get my domain?

Comment: this is possible, or you make a 2D plot

Comment: post your results and we can compare ours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to describe the domain of $f$ is by stating a $y$-dependent interval for the allowed values of $x$:
$$
y^2-4y+3 < x \leq y-1
$$
You could if you wish add the condition that $1\leq y \leq 4$ but that would be redundant, since it is always satisfied whenever $y^2-4y+3 < x \leq y-1$ can be satisfied for any $x$.